# Succeed in survival?

Tags: expressions

> If you can start a campfire, you will 50% succeed in survival.

Can someone say if the sentence above is gramatically correct or not?

Comment: The proper way to ask is "Can someone say if the sentence above is grammatically correct?" When there is a "if" the phrase "or not" is redundant. In fact, you should simply ask, "Is the the sentence above grammatically correct?"

Comment: H1 Named. Welcome to EL&U! Please wait a day or two before selecting an answer. You may get several more answers with other ideas or different advice. But people may not bother to write you another answer if you've already selected one! (you can unselect it for the time being by clicking on the green tick - you can put it back again later!

Comment: We often use percentages like this to modify nouns. We don't generally use them to modify verbs. You can make the sentence better by using the 50% to modify a noun like *chance*, or using the 50% after the verb *BE*: *If you can start a campfire, you will have a 50% chance of survival* or *If you can start a campfire, the odds of you surviving will be 50%*.

Comment: You might find our sister site for English students helpful. It's called ELL [You can find it here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's grammatically correct, but it's not semantically correct.  Survival is all or nothing.  You either survive or you don't.  There are no half-measures.  One cannot only half succeed in surviving.

If what you want to say is that building a fire increases their odds of success, then say:

> If you can start a campfire, you will have a 50% chance of success in
>   surviving.

Or you can simply say:

> If you can start a campfire, you will have a 50% chance of surviving.

Comment: No idea what you are expounding.

Comment: @Blessed Geek : I'm not expounding.  I'm saying that surviving is like a light switch: It's either on or it's off.  One can't half survive because if you haven't fully survived, then you're dead.

Comment: Is it "semantically incorrect" for someone to say to his family after a long bicycle tourney, "I'm half-dead" ? Because according to you, you are either dead or alive.

Comment: Given that the asker's "succeed" actually meant "succeeding" or "success", any statistician who encounters the phrase "you have 50% success in survival" or "you have 50% succeeding in survival", we will have no objection to the phrases being mathematically/logically acceptable statements.

Comment: I believe that the op meant "If you can start a campfire, your chance of success in surviving will raise to 50%".

Comment: @Blessed Geek : It is only semantically correct for someone to say to his family after a long bicycle tourney, "I'm half-dead," if that someone is being purposefully hyperbolic.  Hyperbole isn't intended to be literal.  When we're being hyperbolic, we say all sorts of things that aren't true.  That's what hyperbole is.

Comment: @Blessed Geek : As to whether starting a camp fire actually increases odds of survival to 50%, I have no idea.  Maybe it does.  Maybe it doesn't. That aspect I leave up to the writer.  For all we know, this was just an example of what the writer wanted to say.

Comment: Then, you do agree that besides the asker using the word "succeed" rather than "success" or "succeeding", there is nothing logically, mathematically, or "semantically" wrong with the sentence?